# Optimal programming approach to work with Vuforia SDK?

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Vuforia with Unity3D or Vuforia with Android studio(native coding)? Whats the best approach to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vuforia with Unity3D makes more sense.

It is simple as this:

If you are making **only** Android app, go for Vuforia with Android Studio. This App will work on Android devices.

If you plan to release this on *iOS*, *Windows Phone*, *HoloLens* then you have to use Vuforia with Unity3D or else, you will end of writing one app in Java(Android), one Object-C/Swift(iOS) and the one one in C#/C++(Windows Phone/HoloLens).

The decision is **no** longer hard to make from here.

Comment: Could also be a matter of license. With Unity, you may have to buy pro.

Comment: I really don't think so. Post I saw about is are from 2010 to 2013. Since Unity 5, this is not true. You can post link to prove this.

Comment: What posts drom 2013? To prove what? That unity pro requires a license? Vuforia with android, you pay for Vuforia. Vuforia with Unity, you pay for Vuforia and unity, based on your revenue. I could send you our invoices as proof.

Comment: **"With Unity, you may have to buy pro"** I am saying that you don't need to buy Unity pro to use Vuforia...You can use Unity free version with Vuforia

Comment: Oh yes but the initial issue was whether android or unity. Im just adding that if we were t....naah whatever.

Comment: @Programmer, what do you suggest reg scripting language in Unity?

Comment: C#. That's it. IT has more features than Javascript/Unity script and you will get more support from that here.

Comment: I would like to use Unity. But now, I have a question that, is it required to use Unity pro only ? @everts

Comment: If you want to use Unity just go for it. You don't need pro to use Vuforia.